# Not redirecting to login page after session time out in mvc 3 application even after specifying forms in authentication tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

Not redirecting to log in page after session time out in mvc 3 application even after specifying forms in authentication tag.
Here is web.config code:-

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="http://localhost/securityManager/Account/LogOn" timeout="1" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" defaultUrl="http://localhost:50008"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: would suggest paste content from you webconfig for Session and Forms Auth

Comment: @PrerakK added web.config code

Comment: what is the session time out you have specified in your config

Comment: I have added authorization tag were it denies anonymous users. The redirection to login page happens after session time out

Comment: I have a two mvc application. First one is used for authentication and other one has reports in .aspx asp .net format. when I am on this asp .net reports, I am  unable to logout even after session timed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

In short...

```
To configure forms authentication across applications, you set attributes
of the forms and machineKey sections of the Web.config file to the same
values for all applications that are participating in shared forms 
authentication.
```

Comment: Yes as per this link I set the same machine and validation key across apps. But still not getting redirected to the login page after session timeout

Comment: Please make sure the timeout for session and forms authentication is same.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I have also added session time out and it works now on server. I wonder whats makes it to work after adding session time out in web config.